# TextBox with TextMode="Date" does not show data

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Gridview, with a DateTime column defined like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
  <EditItemTemplate>
     <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" Text='<%# Item.Date.ToShortDateString() %>' runat="server" TextMode="Date"></asp:TextBox>
  </EditItemTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="lblDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Item.Date.ToShortDateString() %>'></asp:Label>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

The date gets displayed in the grid, and it gets saved correctly when I edit a row from the grid. The only problem is that "txtDate" doesn't display the current value when entering in "edit mode" of a row. It displays "mm/dd/yyyy" instead of the actual value coming from the bind. And I don't know why. Nonetheless, when I remove the property TextMode="Date", the actual value displays correctly.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This occurs in Google Chrome when the browser can't parse the given date. You should be getting a warning about that in the browser's console as well. Google Chrome expects the format to be `yyyy-MM-dd`, so e.g.:

```
Item.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: It also happens in Edge, but not in FireFox. I don't know what the format is for FireFox: I tried all formats but nothing seems to work.